# How to inform polkadot.js wallet to approve erc20-type token transfer?

Tags: smart-contract, ink, astar

I am developing **smart contract that can stake erc20-type token**, and testing it on shibuya testnet. But i have some problems. My staking contract have to request erc20-type token contract to approve for transfer, however, I could not find a proper answer. Inevitably I used an alternative trick. Following is my test code.

```
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]
use ink_lang as ink;
#[ink::contract]
mod staking {
    // -- snip --

    #[ink(storage)]
    pub struct Staking {
        staked: StorageHashMap<AccountId, Vec<Stake>>,
        unstaked: StorageHashMap<AccountId, Vec<Balance>>,
        staking_time: Balance,
        block_time: Balance,
        token: Erc20Ref,
    }

    #[derive(
        Copy,
        Clone,
        Ord,
        Eq,
        Default,
        PackedLayout,
        SpreadLayout,
        scale::Encode,
        scale::Decode,
    )]
    #[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(scale_info::TypeInfo))]
    pub struct Stake {
        amount: Balance,
        timestamp: Balance,
    }

    impl Staking {

        // -- snip --

        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn stake(&mut self, _amount: Balance) {
            let caller = self.env().caller();
            
            // -- snip --
            
            // This line is additive code for an alternative way.
            self.token.approve_from_to(caller, self.env().account_id(), _amount);
            self.token.transfer_from(caller, self.env().account_id(), _amount);
        }
```

And this is erc20-type token code.

```
/// If this function is called again it overwrites the current allowance with `value`.
///
/// An `Approval` event is emitted.
#[ink(message)]
pub fn approve_from_to(&mut self, from: AccountId, to: AccountId, value: Balance) -> Result<()> {
    self.allowances.insert((&from, &to), &value);
    self.env().emit_event(Approval {
         owner: from,
         spender: to,
         value,
    });
    Ok(())
}
```

But it is too dangerous code. Please help my problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have a link to the repo? I would like to look deeper into the project and see how you are sending the transaction. Generally, you should be able to call the function using https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/tree/master/packages/api-contract

Comment: Can you clarify what "But it is too dangerous code" means?

Comment: I don't understand the problem from the question at all. I could only guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for `contract-pallet` and WASM-related contracts was defined a standard [`PSP22`](https://github.com/w3f/PSPs/blob/master/PSPs/psp-22.md) for fungible tokens.

If you want to interact with that standard you need to do cross-contract calls with the right selectors(identifiers of methods) and expected input arguments.

For example, you can use the [`PSP22` trait](https://github.com/Supercolony-net/openbrush-contracts/blob/main/contracts/traits/psp22/psp22.rs#L16) from OpenBrush library to do that.

For that, you need to import `brush` into `Cargo.toml` like [here](https://docs.openbrush.io/smart-contracts/overview#the-default-toml-of-your-project-with-openbrush).

And after you can write something like:

```rust
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]
use ink_lang as ink;
#[ink::contract]
mod staking {
    use brush::contracts::traits::psp22::PSP22Ref;

    #[ink(storage)]
    pub struct Staking {
        // ...
        token: AccountId,
    }

    impl Staking {
        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn stake(&mut self, _amount: Balance) {
            let caller = self.env().caller();
            PSP22Ref::transfer_from(&self.token,  caller,  self.env().account_id(), _amount, Vec::<u8>::new())?;
        }
```

In that case, the caller of your staking contract should approve transfer via the `PSP22::approve` function.

Comment: Can you provide an example on how to call the approve function from the front end ? 

The following has not worked : 

let Contract = new ContractPromise(api, abi_psp22, tokenAddress);
  Contract.tx['psp22::approve'](tokensAddress, SpenderContractAddress, formattedAmount)